# What is the equivalent of Go's select case paradigm for channels in Rust?

Tags: rust, channel

Is there is a way to use Rust's channels like Go? I couldn't find any.

For those who are not familiar with select  statement in Go (from [the documentation](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Select_statements)):

> A "select" statement chooses which of a set of possible send or receive operations will proceed. It looks similar to a "switch" statement but with the cases all referring to communication operations.
>   A case with a RecvStmt may assign the result of a RecvExpr to one or two variables, which may be declared using a short variable declaration. The RecvExpr must be a (possibly parenthesized) receive operation. There can be at most one default case and it may appear anywhere in the list of cases.
>
> Execution of a "select" statement proceeds in several steps:
>
> 1. For all the cases in the statement, the channel operands of receive operations and the channel and right-hand-side expressions of send statements are evaluated exactly once, in source order, upon entering the "select" statement. The result is a set of channels to receive from or send to, and the corresponding values to send. Any side effects in that evaluation will occur irrespective of which (if any) communication operation is selected to proceed. Expressions on the left-hand side of a RecvStmt with a short variable declaration or assignment are not yet evaluated.
> 2. If one or more of the communications can proceed, a single one that can proceed is chosen via a uniform pseudo-random selection. Otherwise, if there is a default case, that case is chosen. If there is no default case, the "select" statement blocks until at least one of the communications can proceed.
> 3. Unless the selected case is the default case, the respective communication operation is executed.
> 4. If the selected case is a RecvStmt with a short variable declaration or an assignment, the left-hand side expressions are evaluated and the received value (or values) are assigned.
> 5. The statement list of the selected case is executed.
>
> Since communication on nil channels can never proceed, a select with only nil channels and no default case blocks forever.

For example, how can I write this in Rust?

```golang
func search(ctx context.Context, result chan IResult, q string) error {
    // googleSearch and bingSearch will return IResult interface channel
    google := googleSearch(q)
    bing := bingSearch(q)
    t := time.After(time.Second)

    for {
        select {
           // at any point if caller cancel the operation we return
           case <- ctx.Done():
               return nil
           case r, ok := <- google:
               if !ok { // check if channel is closed
                  google = nil
                  if bing == nil { // we are done
                     return nil
                  }
                  continue
               }
               // sending the google search result to result channel. ( channel to channel )
               result <- r
           case r, ok := <- bing:
               if !ok {
                  bing = nil
                  if google == nil {
                     return nil
                  }
                  continue
               }
               result <- r
           case <- t:
               // this function never lives for more then 1 second
               return fmt.Errorf("timeout")
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

Answer (score 5):

For the channels in the standard library, the most useful answer is "there isn't one".

The technically correct answer is the [`select!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.select.html) macro:

```
select! {
    r = result.recv() => {
        // do something
    }
    _ = something_that_waits_a_second.recv() => {
        // timeout
    }
}
```

(Note that this is the equivalent of [OP's original example](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/52302371/2), before it was drastically changed).

It's unstable, which is why I classify it as not useful.

Beyond the stability of `select!` there's other concerns. For example, in your Go example, you create something that will magically submit into a channel after some time (`time.After(time.Second)`). Rust has no always-running runtime to drive these things. That means you would need to spawn an OS-level thread to wait for a while and push a value into the channel to perform that timeout! This is pretty inefficient.

---

If you are really looking for something closer to Go's green threads, I'd advocate looking into futures instead:

```rust
use futures::{prelude::*, stream}; // 0.3.1
use std::time::Duration;
use tokio::time; // 0.2.10

fn example() -> impl Stream<Item = Result<String, &'static str>> {
    let searches = stream::select(google_search(), bing_search());
    let deadline = time::delay_for(Duration::from_secs(1)).into_stream();

    stream::select(searches.map(Ok), deadline.map(|_| Err("timeout")))
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let result = example()
        .try_for_each(|r| async move {
            println!("Search result: {}", r);
            Ok(())
        })
        .await;

    if let Err(e) = result {
        println!("Had an error: {}", e);
    }
}

fn google_search() -> impl Stream<Item = String> {
    let results = (0..10).map(|x| format!("goog{}", x));
    let results = stream::iter(results);

    // Fake some delay between results
    let delay = time::interval(Duration::from_millis(75));
    results.zip(delay).map(|(r, _)| r)
}

fn bing_search() -> impl Stream<Item = String> {
    let results = (0..10).map(|x| format!("bing{}", x));
    let results = stream::iter(results);

    // Fake some delay between results
    let delay = time::interval(Duration::from_millis(200));
    results.zip(delay).map(|(r, _)| r)
}
```

The `#[tokio::main]` annotation is implicit in every Go program; that's starting an asynchronous reactor and running it "to completion".

Comment: "there isn't one" Well, how about [`recv_timeout`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/mpsc/struct.Receiver.html#method.recv_timeout)? We don't need a special syntax or macro if it can be implemented in a library.

Comment: @mcarton I think an answer showing that would be useful! I don't know enough about Go to truly know if Go's `select` can be (trivially?) implemented in Rust.

Comment: `crossbeam_channel` also seems to have something similar to Go's channel and select. But my knowledge of Go basically stops at ["lol no generics"](https://www.reddit.com/r/gobashing/).

Comment: @mcarton: Then you'll be pleased to know that for Go 2.0 the Go team is looking into syntactic sugar for error handling and generics :)

Answer (score 5):

If you just want to receive with a timeout, the [`recv_timeout`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/mpsc/struct.Receiver.html#method.recv_timeout) method is what you are looking for.

There is also a [`try_recv`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/mpsc/struct.Receiver.html#method.try_recv) method, if you want to receive without blocking.

If you want to mix several channels, then [@Shepmaster's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52303269/2733851) describes the only way I know of in the standard library.

However Rust's standard library is much more lightweight than Go's, and in Rust it is common to use crates for this kind of thing. The [`crossbeam_channel`](https://crates.io/crates/crossbeam-channel) crate does have a [`select`](https://docs.rs/crossbeam-channel/0.2.5/crossbeam_channel/#select) that is stable and can be used to wait on different channels.

Comment: I think that `try_recv` would need to be stuck in a loop of some sort, trying each channel in turn until one has data. I believe this would cause 100% processor usage.

Comment: The [implementation of crossbeam's `select`](https://docs.rs/crossbeam-channel/0.2.5/src/crossbeam_channel/internal/select.rs.html#589-1614) is wild.

Comment: @Shepmaster the `try_recv` is more about replacing the first use of select in [this example](https://gobyexample.com/non-blocking-channel-operations). And I expected no less from a macro such as `select` :D